# swifty Json parse data show me nil?

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

fail parsing data

```
  let tag:string = "\(sender.tag)"
  let name:string = (self.json?["data"][tag]["name"].stringValue)!
```

success parse data

```
  let tag:Int = sender.tag
  let name:String = (self.json?["data"]["\(tag)"]["name"].stringValue)!
```

what different about tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sender tags only take `Int` values and they also give Int `values`. You simply just can't take tag as `String` and set it as `String`.

You can even test it without your parsig. Simply test it with buttons.

Comment: Thanks your advice.Help me a lot.